# Flickity carousel doesn't work if used (ngfor)

Tags: angular, carousel, flickity

I'm using a carousel called flickity

when I'm using static data the carousel works normally

- normal behavior code:

  ```
  <div class="carousel" data-flickity='{"autoPlay": "10000", "wrapAround": true, "imagesLoaded": true}'>
    <a href="">
      <img class="carousel-cell"
        src="https://149634564.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/rober-gonzalez-ShXbeohihGo-unsplash-800x550.jpg"
        alt="">
    </a>

    <a href="">
      <img class="carousel-cell"
        src="https://149634564.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/niklas-veenhuis-TEjATSCI2A4-unsplash-800x550.jpg"
        alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  ```

but when I request data then use *ngfor it shows all slides as one block, no sliding.

- not working code:

  ```
    <div class="carousel cssanimation sequence fadeInBottom" #carousel
  data-flickity='{"autoPlay": "10000", "wrapAround": true, "imagesLoaded": true}'>

  <a href="" *ngFor="let show of RecentReleases">
    <img class="carousel-cell" [src]="show.largePoster" alt="poster">
  </a> </div>
  ```
- my ts code:

  ```
  RecentReleases?: IShow[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.homeService.getRecentReleases().subscribe((shows) => {
      this.RecentReleases = shows;
    });
  }
  ```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

-Edit 1: when I initialized the "RecentRleleases" with a static data it worked correctly so I think the problem in waiting the data ?

Comment: Might be due to the fact that `RecentReleases` can be null. Try to add a `*ngIf="RecentReleases"` to the parent `div`.

Comment: tried it, didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think the code should be:

```html
<div *ngIf="RecentReleases?.length > 0" class="carousel" data-flickity='{"autoPlay": "10000", "wrapAround": true, "imagesLoaded": true}'>
  <a href="" *ngFor="let show of RecentReleases">
    <img class="carousel-cell"
      [src]="show.largePoster"
      alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

in order to reproduce the "normal behavior code"

Comment: edited the code in the question above, as I couldn't format it correctly .. I'm using the same code, i think the problem because the fetching of the data takes time, so I should wait some time before initialize the slider ?

Comment: yes maybe you should initialize the slider after you assign `this.RecentReleases = shows;` but maybe this fixes the problem: `<div *ngIf="RecentReleases?.length > 0" class="carousel" data-flickity='{"autoPlay": "10000", "wrapAround": true, "imagesLoaded": true}'>`

Comment: tried it but it didn't wokr :(

Comment: then probably you need to initialize flickity using Javscipt instead of HTML

Comment: can you kindly illustrate how to do so ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you try to create the carousel, the elements are not in the screen. As Zerotwelve say you need initialize using javascript. Where? in subscribe function and enclosed in a setTimeout to give time to Angular to repaint the elements

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.homeService.getRecentReleases().subscribe((shows) => {
    this.RecentReleases = shows;
    setTimeout(()=>{
       const flkty = new Flickity( '.main-carousel', {
      // options
        cellAlign: 'left',
        contain: true
      });
      flkty.resize() //<--add this line
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use this way but it seems I can't, can you kindly illustratre it more or apply it in my code above.
thanks

Comment: @EmadNaeim, I only follow the [document](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) when say: "Initialize with vanilla Javascript". See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-prnevm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,angular.json,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fpolyfills.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhome.service.ts)

Comment: Maybe it would be better to initialize it in `ngAfterViewInit` so you don't need a `setTimeout`, don't you think @Eliseo ?

Comment: @Zerotwelve, not. You need give Angular time to draw the "slider". I use a setTimeout(), you can use also [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) to say Angular that "check again", But you need to have the "sliders" in the screen before create the Flickity. BTW, I update the answer adding a ` flkty.resize()` to reinit